# If $\xi:[0,1]\to[0,1)$ is decreasing, is $[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\xi(1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\xi(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$ eventually nonincreasing?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, monotone-functions

Let $$\iota:[0,\infty)\to[0,1)\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor,$$ $\xi:[0,1]\to[0,1)$ be decreasing and $$\tilde\xi(t):=\xi(1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\left(\xi\circ\iota\right)(t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$

> Are we able to show that $[t_0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\tilde\xi(t)$ is nonincreasing for some sufficiently large $t_0\ge0$?

The first factor $$[0,\infty)\ni t\mapsto\xi(1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\tag1$$ is clearly nonincreasing.

Now let $t>s\ge0$. If $s=n+r_1$ and $t=n+r_2$ for some $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $r_i\in[0,1)$ with $r_1<r_2$, then we clearly obtain $\tilde\xi(s)>\tilde\xi(t)$.

So, the crucial case is $s=m+r_1$ and $t=n+r_2$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $r_i\in[0,1)$ with $m<n$. Maybe we can find $t_0\ge0$ so that as long as $t>s\ge t_0$, it still holds $\tilde\xi(s)>\tilde\xi(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't miss something, it is almost trivially true that $\tilde{\xi}$ is decreasing without the additional restriction on domain you impose. For $n-1 \leq s < t \leq n$ one has
$$\tilde{\xi}(t) = \xi(1)^{\lceil t\rceil - 1} \xi(t - \lceil t \rceil + 1) = \xi(1)^{\lfloor s\rfloor} \xi(t - \lceil t \rceil + 1) <  \xi(1)^{\lfloor s \rfloor} \xi(s -\lfloor s\rfloor) = \tilde{\xi}(s)$$
since $t - \lceil t \rceil  + 1 > s - \lfloor s \rfloor$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but by restricting $s,t$ to lie in $[n-1,n]$, aren't you considering the first case I've already handled in the question once again? My problem is the proof of the case $s<t$ with $m<n$. By the way, I don't see the benefit in rewriting these things in terms of the ceil-function. Note that $t-\lceil t\lceil+1=r_2=t-\lfloor t\rfloor$. And $s-\lfloor s\rfloor=r_1$.

Comment: No. In the question you deal with the half open interval $[n-1, n)$. This answer is a slight extension but it is sufficient for the result since one only needs to consider the case $n = m + 1$ in your problem case; I just do both cases at once. You should notice that if $t$ is an integer $t - \lceil t \rceil+ 1 = 1 \neq t - \lfloor t \rfloor$.

Comment: Why am I dealing with $[n-1,n)$? If $s,t\in[n,n+1)$, we are in the case $m=n$, aren't we? (Regarding $t-\lceil t\rceil+1=t-\lfloor t\rfloor$: Yes, you're right, but it only fails to hold if $t$ is an integer.)

Comment: In the question you deal with the case $s = n + r_1$ and $t \in n + r_2$ with $r_i \in [0,1)$, i.e. $s,t$ are in the same interval of length $1$ that does not include the right endpoint. My answer includes the right end point so that I deal with the case $n = m+1$ and $r_2 = 0$ which is all that's needed which btw that means $t$ an integer is the key case.

Comment: I see, but the crucial point of the question I'm asking is why is that all that's needed? Cases like $m=0$, $n=1$, $r_1=.9$, $r_2=.1$ seem to be problematic.

Comment: Seriously? If $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$... 
$$\tilde{\xi}(0.9) > \tilde{\xi}(1) > \tilde{\xi}(1+0.1)$$

Comment: You're right. That was a stupid comment. The thing is that I was on the wrong track thinking that we need to use $\xi(1)=\inf_{[0,\:1]}\xi$ at some point.

Comment: If $t=n$, then $\lfloor t\rfloor=n\ne n-1=\lceil t\rceil-1$. So, in that case your first equality in your displayed equation fails to hold.

Comment: That's the point. In that case $\xi(t - \lceil t \rceil + 1) = \xi(1)$ which accounts for the missing power.

Comment: Now I got it! Stopped thinking about the second term.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this post again, but didn't you forget a factor of $\xi(0)$ in $\tilde{\xi}(t) = \xi(1)^{\lceil t\rceil - 1} \xi(t - \lceil t \rceil + 1)$? If $r_2=1$, then $\tilde\xi(t)=\xi(1)^{n+1}\xi(0)$, but $\xi(1)^{\lceil t\rceil-1}\xi(t-\lceil t\rceil+1)=\xi(1)^{n+1}$. Since $\xi(0)\le 1$, the result $\tilde\xi(s)=\xi(1)^n\xi(r_1)\ge\xi(1)^{n+1}\ge\xi(1)^{n+1}\xi(0)=\tilde\xi(t)$ remains correct though.

Comment: I implicitly assumed you intended $\xi(0) = 1$ since otherwise $\tilde{\xi}$ doesn't extend $\xi$ (they differ at $1$). If you want to allow $\xi(0) < 1$ then you need to add that factor but this causes no problems (it just makes the left hand side of the inequalities smaller).

Comment: I'm not sure whether the monotonicity of $\tilde\xi$ is the crucial ingredient, but do you have an idea how we can extend this inequality: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3722993/47771?